# AngularJS Select Initial Value Not Selecting

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using an HTML select with the following data and scope code (below). I cannot get the initial value to select in the Select list from the scope data. Can someone point out what I'm messing up?

```
   $scope.hourOptions = [
            { value:'0',  key: '12AM'},
            { value:'3600',  key: '1AM'},
            { value:'7200',  key: '2AM'},
            { value:'10800',  key: '3AM'},
            { value:'14400',  key: '4AM'},
            { value:'18000',  key: '5AM'},
            { value:'21600',  key: '6AM'},
            { value:'25200',  key: '7AM'},
            { value:'28800',  key: '8AM'},
            { value:'32400',  key: '9AM'},
            { value:'36000', key: '10AM'},
            { value:'39600', key: '11AM'},
            { value:'43200', key: '12AM'},
            { value:'46800', key: '1PM'},
            { value:'50400', key: '2PM'},
            { value:'54000', key: '3PM'},
            { value:'57600', key: '4PM'},
            { value:'61200', key: '5PM'},
            { value:'64800', key: '6PM'},
            { value:'68400', key: '7PM'},
            { value:'72000', key: '8PM'},
            { value:'75600', key: '9PM'},
            { value:'79200', key: '10PM'},
            { value:'82800', key: '11PM'}
        ];
```

Here's the view

```
<select id="timeOfDay" class="form-control"
        data-ng-options="option.value as option.key for option in hourOptions"
        data-ng-model="topic.timeOfDay"
        required
        ></select>
```

The $scope.topic value is set to 72000 as such:

```
$scope.topic.timeOfDay = 72000;
```

I've tried changing this to a string in the data-ng-init with no avail. Regardless what I do I cannot get the initial value to select itself in the select list. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `option.value` is string representation of numeric value you must provide ng-model value as string as well. And initialize it in the controller instead of using [`ng-init`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit) for initializing (though it wont cause an issue, but just that usage of it to initialize like this is not a good pattern)

Try:

```
$scope.timeOfDay = '72000';
```

and probably you meant to set ng-model as `data-ng-model="timeOfDay"` or viceversa.

**[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Itm8AN?p=preview)**

Comment: This was the problem. For some reason, the ng-init didn't do anything (though I assumed it would). Setting it to a string in the controller did the trick. I updated my code sample to be correct (had a typo with the scope setting). Thanks!

Comment: @DonnFelker You are welcome. ng-init expression is not watched and you do not use `$scope` explicity in ng-init, scope is implicit there. However it is not a good thing to initialize in ng-init as the ofiicial doc says.